# Can't remove unused package in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer made me aware that a package was outdated, and needed upgrading.

```
1 package is not up to date:
 - google/cloud (v0.49.0) latest is v0.69.0
```

This package was unknown to me, but I am working with several other developers, so I checked:

```
$ composer why google/cloud
There is no installed package depending on "google/cloud"
```

Long story short, I am having difficulties removing this package. For instance with remove:

```
$ composer remove google/cloud
google/cloud is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
```

I even tried `composer require google/cloud:^0.49`, and then did `composer remove google/cloud` afterwards, 
…but it is not removed from the `vendor` folder or the `composer.lock` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A month later I think I found the answer by accident:

```
$ composer why google/cloud-storage
google/cloud                          v0.49.0  replaces  google/cloud-storage (1.3.0)       
superbalist/flysystem-google-storage  7.0.0    requires  google/cloud-storage (>=1.0 <1.4)
```

So composer can't see why `google/cloud` is required, since `google/cloud-storage` is the one that is really required, but it is replaced by `google/cloud`. Or so it might seem.